# Responsive Absolute Placed Image

Tags: html, css

I have a Section with four blocks of content. On the right-hand side of the screen, I have some images (shapes in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MJoL.png)), that I would place in absolute position. The issue I'm facing is that these images will move into the text when the screen width becomes smaller.

Is there a way to keep the images from doing this or maybe a better approach?

My code would look something like

```css
.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 100px 0px
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 100px 0px;
}

.place-1, .place-2, .place-3 {
  position: absolute
}

.place-1 {
  top: 5%;
  right: 0%;
  max-width: 30%
}

.place-2 {
  top: 30%;
  right: 5%;
  max-width: 30%
}

.place-3 {
  top: 65%;
  right: -15%;
  max-width: 30%
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac convallis quam. Maecenas facilisis nisi ut scelerisque dapibus. Nulla rutrum varius arcu a pharetra. Etiam vel lobortis erat. Vestibulum lobortis commodo interdum. Etiam eu sapien erat. Suspendisse cursus quam enim, sed lobortis erat vehicula sed. Aenean suscipit eget quam sed iaculis. Integer vehicula mollis nisi eget volutpat. In eget massa vestibulum, sodales turpis nec, tincidunt leo. Curabitur ullamcorper mi eu vestibulum luctus. Proin at lacus molestie odio iaculis vehicula et rutrum erat. Integer nec ipsum nec dolor ultrices scelerisque. Maecenas pharetra lacus in efficitur scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac convallis quam. Maecenas facilisis nisi ut scelerisque dapibus. Nulla rutrum varius arcu a pharetra. Etiam vel lobortis erat. Vestibulum lobortis commodo interdum. Etiam eu sapien erat. Suspendisse cursus quam enim, sed lobortis erat vehicula sed. Aenean suscipit eget quam sed iaculis. Integer vehicula mollis nisi eget volutpat. In eget massa vestibulum, sodales turpis nec, tincidunt leo. Curabitur ullamcorper mi eu vestibulum luctus. Proin at lacus molestie odio iaculis vehicula et rutrum erat. Integer nec ipsum nec dolor ultrices scelerisque. Maecenas pharetra lacus in efficitur scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac convallis quam. Maecenas facilisis nisi ut scelerisque dapibus. Nulla rutrum varius arcu a pharetra. Etiam vel lobortis erat. Vestibulum lobortis commodo interdum. Etiam eu sapien erat. Suspendisse cursus quam enim, sed lobortis erat vehicula sed. Aenean suscipit eget quam sed iaculis. Integer vehicula mollis nisi eget volutpat. In eget massa vestibulum, sodales turpis nec, tincidunt leo. Curabitur ullamcorper mi eu vestibulum luctus. Proin at lacus molestie odio iaculis vehicula et rutrum erat. Integer nec ipsum nec dolor ultrices scelerisque. Maecenas pharetra lacus in efficitur scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac convallis quam. Maecenas facilisis nisi ut scelerisque dapibus. Nulla rutrum varius arcu a pharetra. Etiam vel lobortis erat. Vestibulum lobortis commodo interdum. Etiam eu sapien erat. Suspendisse cursus quam enim, sed lobortis erat vehicula sed. Aenean suscipit eget quam sed iaculis. Integer vehicula mollis nisi eget volutpat. In eget massa vestibulum, sodales turpis nec, tincidunt leo. Curabitur ullamcorper mi eu vestibulum luctus. Proin at lacus molestie odio iaculis vehicula et rutrum erat. Integer nec ipsum nec dolor ultrices scelerisque. Maecenas pharetra lacus in efficitur scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;</p>
  </div>
  <img class="place-1" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500">
  <img class="place-2" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300">
  <img class="place-3" src="https://picsum.photos/700/700">
</div>
```

Comment: you can add `z-index = '-1'`  to `img` for better view.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What are you actually trying to accomplish? Using `position: absolute` might not be the best approach. This might be an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. Also, update your image `src` with an actual image  - something from https://picsum.photos/ would work.

Comment: @disinfor Its not as easy to reflect the problem I have with this mock up code, please take a look at the link with the mock up I've attached. The issue I'm having is on smaller width screens some shapes clip into the text, for example the red triangle on smaller laptop screens clips into top paragraph instead of remaining inbetween both paragraphs. Is there a way to have this image be place using absolute but also be responsive to keep that overall look?

Comment: So, it looks like you are placing shapes in a "random" pattern, and on small screens, you don't want them to overlap the text. Do you want each shape to go in between (underneath and above) the paragraph it's next to? If so, we might need to change your markup. The biggest issue is that `position: absolute` removes the element from document flow, so there is no way for the `p` elements to know that they should respond to those elements.

Comment: @disinfor, Yes! That's what I am trying to keep. I am trying to keep the images between each paragraph as you had said. Whilst keeping it responsive. Here's a [website] (https://flightframework.com) I found that is similar. Take a look at the feathers surrounding the book or under the Framework Purpose area you can see the feather go between paragraphs in smaller windows.

Answer (score 0):

This your code is wrong! `.place-1,.place-2,.place-3` is correct. you should place a `,` between of the name of classes:

```css
.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.place-1,.place-2,.place-3 {
  position: absolute;
}

.place-1 {
  top: 5%;
  right: 0%;
  max-width: 30%
}

.place-2 {
  top: 30%;
  right: 5%;
  max-width: 30%
}

.place-3 {
  top: 5%;
  right: -15%;
  max-width: 30%
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum....</p>
  </div>
  <img class="place-1" src="...">
  <img class="place-2" src="...">
  <img class="place-3" src="...">
</div>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, I just wrote it up quickly, this doesn't really solve the problem I am having though. Thanks for the catch though!